# Shiny:How to avoid global variables and problem with ggplot one observation at a time

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am building a shiny application where every 30 secs, `reactivefilereader` reads in  new data and process it by appending to data accumulated since the the app starts running (the data processing function append new data with existing aggregated data and returns one single row), and then `ggplot` will plot this single observation on the plot. And it will plot out the observations continuously with a line. However, I received this error message and nothing is being plotted on the shiny app.

```
geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

My data is as follow:

```
ts
                          Px
2020-03-13 17:15:19.000 23335.5
```

I have the global variable outside the `server` function. Note that below doesn't contain any data because the shiny will read in the data every 30 seconds.

```
ggprice   <-  ggplot() + scale_colour_manual(values=c(Px="black"))
```

And the plot is updated through below and `ts` is the data. And it will contain ONLY one observation.

```
ggprice   <<-    ggprice   + geom_line(aes(x=Index,y=Px,colour = "Px"),data=ts)
```

How do I overcome this ?

**Update: A reproducible example as requested.**

I have 2 global variables below, which i know are super clumsy.

1. Global variable 1 - `xts_bars_Agg` used to store all the processed data since the app starts running
2. Global variable 2 - `ggprice`. Every new observation is appended on this global variable by `geom_line(...)`.

**How can this be optimized ? Can the global variables be avoided here?**

```
# Global variables
xts_bars_Agg <-  NULL


#   --- Function: Data I/O ------------------------------------------------------
data_processing <- function(csv_file){

    df                              <-  read.csv(csv_file, header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,colClasses = c("character","double"))
        # convert String to timestamp, remove string timestamp
        df                          <-  (data.frame( Timestamp = strptime(df[,1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), df[,c(-1)]))
        df_xts                      <-  xts(x=df[,c(-1)], order.by=df$Timestamp)
        xts_bars_Agg                <<- rbind.xts(xts_bars_Agg,df_xts)
        # *** the reason I need to rbind the new df_xts to 
        # existing xts_bars_agg (xts object) 
        # because the computeMagicalVal function below needs 
        # both the previous aggregated xts data plus the current xts data
        # to compute a value.
        # This and the usage of global variable looks very clumsy and inefficient and stupid to me. 
        # Is there a way to optimise this ?
        df_xts_final                 <- computeMagicalVal(xts_bars_Agg)

    # return df_xts_final with only one row, 
    # whereas xts_bars_Agg contains all the xts data with many rows
    return(df_xts_final)
}

# second global variable
# global variable
ggprice      <-  ggplot() +
                scale_colour_manual(values=c(Price="black"))

ggplot_func <- function(ts){
    ggprice      <<-    ggprice      + geom_line(aes(x=Index,y=Px,colour = "Price"),data=ts)
    return(ggprice)
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    #ggplot
    mainPanel(
        plotOutput(outputId = 'ggp')
    )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {    
    df_update <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 10000,session=NULL,
                                    filePath = "output.csv",
                                    readFunc = data_processing)

    output$ggp <- renderPlot({
        ggplot_func(df_update())
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example of your shiny app?

Comment: Also, use global variable in shiny app is not recommended, try to use reactiveValues

Comment: Do you minding putting this as an answer to exemplify it?

Comment: I think I haven't solve you problem yet. If you provide a reproducible example, maybe someone would find the solution of your problem and put it as an answer.

Comment: You are right. I have included my code above. The  global variables look inefficient and convoluted to me as well. Please kindly teach me how to do better here.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide `output.csv`?

Comment: My output only output one single row, as shown above by `ts`, which is time and price. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you could try working with reactive Values like this

```
#   --- Function: Data I/O ------------------------------------------------------
data_processing <- function(csv_file){

  df                              <-  read.csv(csv_file, header=T,stringsAsFactors = F,colClasses = c("character","double"))
  # convert String to timestamp, remove string timestamp
  df                          <-  (data.frame( Timestamp = strptime(df[,1],"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"), df[,c(-1)]))
  df_xts                      <-  xts(x=df[,c(-1)], order.by=df$Timestamp)


  return(df_xts)
}

# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  #ggplot
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput(outputId = 'ggp')
  )
)

# Define server logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  rective_values <- reactiveValues(
    xts_bars_Agg = tibble(),
    ggprice = ggplot() +
      scale_colour_manual(values=c(Price="black"))
  )

  # whereas xts_bars_Agg contains all the xts data with many rows
  observe({
    reactive_values$xts_bars_Agg = rbind.xts(xts_bars_Agg,df_update()) 
    # *** the reason I need to rbind the new df_xts to 
    # existing xts_bars_agg (xts object) 
    # because the computeMagicalVal function below needs 
    # both the previous aggregated xts data plus the current xts data
    # to compute a value.
    # This and the usage of global variable looks very clumsy and inefficient and stupid to me. 
    # Is there a way to optimise this ?
  })

  observeEvent(reactive_values$xts_bars_Agg,{
    df_xts_final = computeMagicalVal(reactive_values$xts_bars_Agg)
    reactive_values$ggprice = reactive_values$ggprice + 
      geom_line(aes(x=Index,y=Px,colour = "Price"),
                data= df_xts_final)
  })
  df_update <- reactiveFileReader(intervalMillis = 10000,session=NULL,
                                  filePath = "output.csv",
                                  readFunc = data_processing)



  output$ggp <- renderPlot({
    reactive_values$ggprice
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: this is a great answer. Is there a way to keep the `ggplot_func` in my code?  Because I actually have multiple plots and I do `grid.arrange` to group multiple plots into one at the end.

Comment: is there a way pass reactive values as arguments into functions ? Can you show me an example plz ? Sorry, as I have been struggling for a while on this.

Comment: yes you can pass the reactive values as parameters to functions you just have to do it within a reactive context such as: reactive observe or render function

Comment: I would put the  function doing the grid.arrange in the renderPlot function

Comment: Do u pass reactive_values or reactive_values$ggprice into the function as an argument in this case ?Or it doesn’t matter ?

Comment: Ithink it would be better to pass `reactive_values$ggprice` other wise you will have to do the selection within the function. But for the function the naming of the variable should actually be irrelevant

Comment: One  thing about the `computeMagicalVal` within the `reactive` expression. When does it get executed ? And in the `observe` `ggprice` expression, the data should also be `df_xts_final`, no ?

Comment: Hi, I changed the code a bit because it is a bad idea to have an reactive call within an observe. Other wise is the rule that reactive object are recalculated as son as any reactive object within them are changed and the result is needed by any object visible in the frontend. observe object are executed as soon any reactibve object within them are changed

Comment: ` df_xts_final <- reactive({computeMagicalVal(reactive_values$xts_bars_Agg)})` is still in the code. Is it meant to be there ? And why not just put ```   reactive_values$ggprice = reactive_values$ggprice +geom_line(aes(x=Index,y=Px,colour = "Price"),data= df_xts_final)``` inside `renderplot`? Since `df_xts_final` changes  as `xts_bars_Agg` changes and `ggprice` is a reactive value.

Comment: And in the `observe` statement, shouldn't it be `rbind.xts(reactive_values$xts_bars_agg,...)`instead of `reactive_values$xts_bars_Agg = rbind.xts(xts_bars_Agg,df_update())` ?

Comment: Apologies here for asking so many questions. But can't I just move `computeMagicalVal` from `observeEvent` to the `observe(...rbind.xts(` ?